# How to use authorization using tokens (Oauth, JWT, etc.) in modern web server applications

Tags: scala, database-design, oauth, playframework, jwt

I am developing a web server application where I need to add authorization. This is the typical flow:

- server issues token(Oauth/JWT) to the client after authentication
- client sends token in each REST API request to server
- server validates token and extracts the privileges held by the owner of this token
- server accordingly fulfills client's request

Question:
Depending on the role of the client, the data from a SQL DB (mysql, oracle, etc.) needs to be returned back to the client. Let's say there are three users each with different roles:

1. userA
2. userB
3. userC

The DB has various tables and depending upon the role of the user the access to the data (tables as well as columns) is allowed.
How do I manage this access ? Should I put this logic of varying access in the web server or it needs to go into DB ?

Making SQL queries on the fly based on user role does not sound practical to me. I am looking for good practices to handle such a scenario.
[I am using Play+Scala for web server]

Comment: _it needs to go into DB_. Do you mean map users roles creating different database users with specific permissions on tables?

Comment: There are no multiple users in the DB which stores by 'business' data (i.e. it's a standard JDBC connection to DB with single user). I need to return specific columns in from a table in this DB depending on who the user is. There is a separate DB which stores user identify (username, password, privileges, etc.).

Comment: If the filter by user role is applied per database column and not per row, to simplify development it is simpler to recover all data in a query and return to client only the available fields for this user. In this way the query is always the same and only changes the way you build the entities to return to client. The performance of the database will not be significantly affected if you use simple types, but if you use blobs you should not read them unless strictly necessary

Comment: @pedrofb Thanks. I believe until I have a working code on this approach I won't know the pros and cons. Would you recommend 'Silhouette' to use as the AA module in play-scala app ?  BTW, I am going to use JWT. Any insights on this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know that software